# Installing MYSQL on Windows Server 2003 - Low Memory Usage Mode

Tags: windows-server-2003, mysql, memory, low-memory

I'd like to setup MySQL on a Windows 2003 server. However, the server is already running SQL Server 2005 and I'd like to reserve most of the 4 GB of memory for that purpose. Is there some way to cap my MySQL at a certain Memory Usage?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Is this a test server?

Comment: nope, it's production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a decent article on [managing MySQL memory usage](http://emergent.urbanpug.com/?p=61). It looks like there is no single setting to set a maximum amount of memory usage, but by adjusting the `key_buffer`, `query_cache_size`, and `max_connections` (among some others) in your `my.cnf`, you can reduce the memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick Mysql on a VM on that same box if at all possible.  I'm not too sure how well sql server and mysql play together.

Comment: MySQL and MSSQL "play fine" together.  Just dont overcommit memory to either.

Comment: as the article in adams answers shows- it's a pain to get mysql to use only X amount of ram- so sticking it in a vm is probably preferable.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you good directions for reducing your base memory usage:

http://www.theodorenguyen-cao.com/2008/12/07/reduce-mysql-memory-usage/

You can then use this to estimate your MySQL memory usages based on the my.ini/my.cnf

http://www.omh.cc/mycnf/

And of course, you should check out the [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/).